# R: What does the y parameter in the createDataPartition function of the caret package do?

Tags: r, caret

I am learning to use the `createDataPartition()` function in package `caret` and do not understand what does the parameter does.

As I understand, the list returned from the function is the row sampled, instead of the value. Why bother picking `y` in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the [data splitting](http://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html) section of the main help pages for `caret`, you'll see the following:

> The function createDataPartition can be used to create balanced splits of the data. If the y argument to this function is a factor, the random sampling occurs within each class and should preserve the overall class distribution of the data.

The rationale for choosing `y` is to be able to preserve an overall class distribution in the outcome more easily. As discussed [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/), there can be many problems with imbalanced classes in your training data.